# Framework to display maps stored on the phone (geotiff)

Tags: android, gis, arcgis

I need to develop an Android application.
The phone it's deplyed on will be completely offline.

The app needs to display maps, which will be stored in the phone's storage.

I will receive the maps in Geotiff format, and can apply pre-processing to alter their format if needed.

What options exists besides Arcgis Android SDK ?

Comment: unfortunately, i don't think you'll find answers for this here, as it'll fall under - 
"Seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more"